# Most efficient way to combine data from different database when join is not possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have two tables of data and I am looking to combine them in single view for reporting purposes (excel and ssrs)

The problem is the view is taking 4 minutes to return 75 rows

Can anyone suggest a better way, I know I could set a job to create a table and update the table overnight and then source my report off the flattened table to improve speed, but is there a better way?

Here is the basic outline and sql

Table 1 is summary data from one database on the server and hold this type on data. This table has 75 rows

```
WageYear    StartDate   EndDate    Week No
2013/14    16/11/2013   22/11/2013  34
2013/14    09/11/2013   15/11/2013  33
2013/14    02/11/2013   08/11/2013  32
2013/14    26/10/2013   01/11/2013  31
```

The second source of data is a view which sits on a selection view that has four outer joins to sub queries and it returns daily occurrence of stock movement with production data calculated - the source table has 1,090,171 rows

```
StockCode   TrnYear TrnMonth    EntryDate   IntoDespKg
Part A      2013    1           06/04/2012  634.5
Part A      2013    1           23/04/2012  634.5
Part B      2013    2           03/05/2012  660
Part B      2013    2           03/05/2012  660
```

The view I have written combines the data and totals the IntoDespKg column so it looks like

```
WageYear    StartDate   EndDate Week No IntoDespKg  TCastKg
2013/14     16/11/2013  22/11/2013   34 141170.925  173840.482
2013/14     09/11/2013  15/11/2013   33 149969.934  134483.17
2013/14     02/11/2013  08/11/2013   32 137661.513  165725.115
2013/14     26/10/2013  01/11/2013   31 137586.634  179026.199
```

My Sql is using sub queries

```
SELECT [WageYear]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[Week No]

  ------------------Std Information------------------
  ,(Select sum ([IntoDespKg]) from [dbo].[CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins] 
        where ([EntryDate] >=W.[StartDate] and [EntryDate] <=W.[EndDate])) As IntoDespKg
  ,(Select sum ([CastKg]) from [dbo].[CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins] 
        where ([EntryDate] >=W.[StartDate] and [EntryDate] <=W.[EndDate])) As [TCastKg]
 ,(Select sum (CoreDirectMins)/60 from [dbo].[CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins] 
        where ([EntryDate] >=W.[StartDate] and [EntryDate] <=W.[EndDate])) As [CoreDirectHrs]       
FROM [Wages].[vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek] W
ORDER BY EndDate DESC
```

Comment: Why have you said *"when join is not possible"*? I can't see why a join isn't possible. Also are any of the columns returned by the view indexed in the underlying table? Could you post the definition of the view as this is almost certainly the source of the problem? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Join is not possible due to performance?

Comment: Your last "aggregation" script is highly inefficient. Try looking into do that with "group by"

Comment: @GraethD How much of the sql do you want to see because there is about 3 layers, which I think is part of the problem. I can post the full script if that helps? The join is not possible more because I can not think of a way of getting the join right!!

Comment: @sam yi yes I agree with your comment but the problem is I can not think of a way of getting the group by right as it is set by the Startdate and EndDate of table 1

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: @IanW If vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek already aggregates some data from CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins, consider creating a view similar to vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek that includes the columns you are summing separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sam Yi pointed out, you can use a simple [`GROUP BY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) statement. If you are expecting date ranges without records in dbo.CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins, then use a `LEFT JOIN`. I also re-aliased your table names.

```
SELECT HoursByAreaByWeek.WageYear
    ,HoursByAreaByWeek.StartDate
    ,HoursByAreaByWeek.EndDate
    ,HoursByAreaByWeek.[Week No]
    ,Sum(RecoveryLabDirectMins.IntoDespKg) As IntoDespKg
    ,Sum(RecoveryLabDirectMins.CastKg) As TCastKg
    ,Sum(CoreDirectMins / 60) As CoreDirectHrs      
FROM Wages.vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek As HoursByAreaByWeek
    JOIN dbo.CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins As RecoveryLabDirectMins
    ON RecoveryLabDirectMins.EntryDate Between HoursByAreaByWeek.StartDate AND HoursByAreaByWeek.EndDate
GROUP BY HoursByAreaByWeek.WageYear
    ,HoursByAreaByWeek.StartDate
    ,HoursByAreaByWeek.EndDate
    ,HoursByAreaByWeek.[Week No]
ORDER BY EndDate DESC
```

Comment: This approach has a big pitfall: if Wages.vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek has a duplicated row, the calculated sums will be wrong.  Without knowing if there is a PK/unique constraint on that table, I strongly recommend against "blind-join grouping" and the nasty silent bugs it can generate.

Comment: @Anon You are right, the view vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek could contain duplicate rows. I leave it to the OP to determine whether there is a unique index on the view or some other guarantee that there will not be duplicate rows. Given that the the name of the view is post-fixed with "ByWeek", I have a feeling the OP will find there are not duplicate rows and will use the more efficient `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: A view named vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek probably isn't just "ByWeek"; it's also "ByArea".  What happens if Areas get added? Removed? Subdivided? That's a huge landmine to leave for maintainers to step on.

Comment: Hi there @Mike  With the information available I thought both answers where great. I not used either approach before but have need something like it and end up running inefficient sql know it was wrong but not knowing the way round the problem, It this case there is a PK on the table below the view. However what does the short hand OP mean please?

Comment: @IanW, OP just means "Original Poster". It is internet slang that refers to the person who started a thread/conversation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [WageYear]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[Week No]

  ------------------Std Information------------------
  ,IntoDespKg
  ,[TCastKg]
  ,[CoreDirectHrs]       
FROM [Wages].[vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek] W
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 
    sum ([IntoDespKg]) IntoDespKg,
    sum ([CastKg]) [TCastKg],
    sum (CoreDirectMins)/60 [CoreDirectHrs]
  from [dbo].[CHCIW_RecoveryLabDirectMins] 
  where ([EntryDate] >=W.[StartDate] and [EntryDate] <=W.[EndDate])
) H
```

Comment: Hi @Anon never seen cross apply before so will have to Google it. Why is this method more of an advantage over the other by @Mike?

Comment: Hi @Anon: I have just run both methods on our server and got a sub-tree cost of 61259.1 cost for your method and  2887.23 for Mike's method. On the little training I have done this (sub tree cost) was the way it was explained to me check the efficiency, although I can understand maintainability would come into it. Needless to say both methods are a VAST improvement on my my method!! :)

Comment: Speed wise, the JOIN will be faster.  It sums the total with the assumption that no two rows will *ever* have overlapping start & end ranges.  If they do, then data gets double-counted and the total will be silently incorrect.  The CROSS APPLY rejects that assumption and calculates the sums safely.  Here are three good ways to protect yourself: 1) Use CROSS APPLY (if is fast enough) 2) Put a PK on vwCHHoursByAreaByWeek (having one on the underlying table is meaningless here) 3) Use WITH SCHEMABINDING (good practice in general, but a pain in the ass if you aren't set up for it)